# Camunda y NestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Estoy usando la librería [camunda-external-task-client-js](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-js) en un proyecto con NestJs y TypeScript y tengo este problema:

```
D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js:18
const camunda_external_task_client_js_1 = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
                                          ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\node_modules\camunda-external-task-client-js\index.js from D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js:18:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.module.js:11:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\main.js:4:22)
```

He intentando solucionarlo cambiando el package.json, el tsconfig.json e inclusive la forma en la que consumo la librería pero nada funciona ¿Existe alguna forma de solucionar el error y/o poner a correrlo junto con un proyecto de NestJs?